# Are there any .NET / JS frameworks for generating web front end based on XML schema?

Tags: xml, web, webforms, schema, dynamically-generated

I am building a site in ASP.NET and JS that allows the user to build up a structured message based on an XML schema in . The XML schema is going to be dynamic so the form needs to be generated based on this and include the client side validation which matches the schema restrictions. Is there any framework available that can help me with this?

Thanks very much for your help